# Using multiple jQuery selectors to filter

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I am trying to add the jQueryUI datepicker on a certain group of datefields, but exclude fields whose id ends in -0

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
            $("input[id^='TOEFLtestDate-']").not([id$='-0']).datepicker({
                onClose: function(dateText, inst){
                    GenericDateUpdate(this.id, dateText,1);
                }
            });
        });
```

This code selects the correct pool of inputs:

```
$(function() {
            $("input[id^='TOEFLtestDate-']").datepicker({
                onClose: function(dateText, inst){
                    GenericDateUpdate(this.id, dateText,1);
                }
            });
        });
```

I just can't seem to get the filtering right to filter out the ids that end in -0.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need quotes in your first attempt, like this:

```
$("input[id^='TOEFLtestDate-']").not("[id$='-0']")
```

Or a bit cleaner, use the [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), like this:

```
 $("input[id^='TOEFLtestDate-']:not([id$='-0'])")
```

Comment: Thanks Nick... you must LIVE on StackOverflow. :-)

Comment: @resonantmedia - Actually I'm building some materialized views at the moment, just answering in-between performance tests :)